# Decoding the returned Array of an USB RFID Reader in PyUSB

Tags: python, arrays, raspberry-pi, pyusb

We are trying to read a number with an (cheap unknown) RFID Reader.

```
dev = usb.core.ding(idVendor = VENDOR_ID, idProduct = PRODUCT_ID)
...
data = dev.read(0x81, 0x80)
print(data)
```

The print outputs

```
array('B', [0, 0, 35, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 33, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 37, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0])
```

When using the RFID Reader it inputs anywhere

```
6b9a0488
```

How does 35 map to 6, 37 to 8 or 5 to b?

Comment: Interesting question. The hex result is 64 bits which suggests you’re using a 64-bit RFID device, but you’re getting 128 separate return values in your array. And they’re not bits because you got numbers like 35 in there

Comment: Are you sure reading from the device at this point really returns something equal to the string you expect (e.g. no missing initialization)? Are you sure requesting data once with a length of 0x80=128 bytes (second parameter of the read function) gives you all the data you need? If not, you might want to use Wireshark to sniff USB communication with the driver shipped with the reader to get an understanding of what data has to be sent and requested (look for "Leftover capture data").